# How to redirect on controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've created a PHP desktop application, but after login, I want to redirect to the controller, but I'm getting error:

`redirect('dashboard');`

> Loading error (-102).

and when I like something this:

`redirect('https://www.google.com/');`

it works.

How can I redirect to a controller?

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();              
        $this->load->model('LoginModel','LoginModel');       
    }    

    public function index()
    {
      if(!empty($_POST))
        {            
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $result = $this->LoginModel->login($email,$password);
            if($result -> num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($result->result() as $row)
                {
                    $this->session->userid = $row->id;
                    $this->session->email=  $row->email;
                    $this->session->is_admin =  $row->is_admin;
                    **redirect('dashboard');**
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $data['email'] = $email;
                $data['password'] = $password;
                $this->session->set_flashdata('SUCCESSMSG','Email and Password is Wrong');
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use redirect to relative path; try something like this:

```
redirect('/controller_name/Dashboard');
```

Comment: Dashboard is route name i set route As Dashroad